# Winform custom control value doesn't get updated from bound property

Tags: winforms, binding, custom-controls

I've created some custom controls that work with databinding.
However, while the first two controls works quite well, I can't understand why this doesn't work.

What should I implement to allow my control bound property to get updated with the source property?
On the other controls I used only a ValueChanged event but it's not working here.

Here's code. What you should know is that CustomAllowedKeys is a list that contains valid Keys in string version

http://pastie.org/2120933

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As microsoft stated, and as I can see over the web, this is a bug found in winform and not fixed.

Best article I found at the moment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Jan/12/More-BindingSource-WinForm-Databinding-frustrations